# Shutdown supervisord on subprocess exit

Tags: docker, supervisord

I'm attempting to run supervisord within a Docker instance.

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:p1]
command=p1 $P1_ENV
autorestart=true
...

[program:p2]
command=p2 $P2_ENV
autorestart=unexpected
...
```

We'd like to be able to run our p2 integration tests within this production Docker instance (currently set up so `P2_ENV=--tests` will run the tests). These tests rely on p1 running. We'd also like for the Docker instance to exit when the tests finish, which requires supervisord to exit.

Is there any to cause supervisord to gracefully quit all processes and exit when process 2 exits gracefully?

If not, is there another supervisord-style program that will allow this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: may be my answer will be right for you http://serverfault.com/questions/760726/how-to-exit-all-supervisor-processes-if-one-exited-with-0-result/762406#762406

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit all supervisor processes if one exited with 0 result](https://serverfault.com/questions/760726/how-to-exit-all-supervisor-processes-if-one-exited-with-0-result)